# How to debug `Error while processing function` in `vim` and `nvim`?

Tags: vim, vimrc

### TL;DR

How to find where exactly `vim` or `nvim` error started (which file?) when I'm interested in fixing the actual issue and not just removing the bad plugin? Anything better than `strace` and guesswork to find the error origin?

### Issue

I often add a plugin to my `vim` or `nvim` config and end up getting errors on hooks (buffer open, close, write):

```py
"test.py" [New] 0L, 0C written
Error detected while processing function 343[12]..272:
line    8:
E716: Key not present in Dictionary: _exec
E116: Invalid arguments for function get(a:args, 'exec', a:1['_exec'])
E15: Invalid expression: get(a:args, 'exec', a:1['_exec'])
```

The problem is, I have no idea where those come from, I only get some line number of unknown file and it's not my `vim`/`nvim` config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular plugin has been written in an object-oriented style. The `343[12]..272` refers to an anonymous (numbered) function in a *Dictionary object*.

If you know the (recently installed) plugin, you can use the `:breakadd file */pluginname.vim` file in your `~/.vimrc` to stop and then step through (with `:next`) it line-by-line.

Alternatively, you can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for the error message and suspect commands before that.